# Pick a specific picture from a list

Tags: haskell, gloss, juicy-pixels

I have the following function:

```
blockToPicture :: Int -> [Picture] -> Picture
blockToPicture n [pic1,pic2,pic3] | n==0 = ...
                                  | n==1 = ...
                                  | otherwise = ...
```

If `n==0` I want to select `pic1`, if `n==1` I want to select `pic2`. Otherwise I want to select `pic3`. The problem is when one of the pictures doesn't load, so it doesn't appear on the list.
Instead of `[pic1,pic2,pic3]` I have something like `[Pic1,Pic3]`.
When the function is `supposed` to select a picture that isn't on the list I want it to write `"X"` instead. For that I'll use the function 
 `text "X"` instead. The problem is that I don't know how to make it write the `"X"` instead of selecting the wrong picture.

Edit:
I've created the following function but for some reason I'm getting the error "Variable not in scope" to the pictures.

```
blocoParaPicture :: Int -> [Picture] -> Picture
blocoParaPicture b l | b==0 = if elem pic1 l then pic1 else text "X"
                     | b==1 = if elem pic2 l then pic2 else text "X"
                     | otherwise = if elem pic3 l then pic3 else text "X"
```

Comment: Well here you could again pattern match on lists like `[pic1, pic2]`, `[pic1]` and `[]`, and each time replace cases that are not covered anymore. But I propose that you implement a recursive pattern where you recurse on a decremented index, and the tail of the list.

Comment: No, no, no, you should use the list of type  `[Maybe Picture]` then.

Comment: What the text “X” function do? may use (Either String Picture) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just discard a picture that doesn't load; if you tried to load 3 pictures and end up with `[some_pic, some_other_pic]`, how do you know which one didn't load? You need a list of type `[Maybe Picture]`, with `Just pic` representing a successfully loaded picture and `Nothing` a failure. Then your function would look like

```
blockToPicture :: Int -> [Maybe Picture] -> Maybe Picture
blockToPicture _ []          = Nothing                  -- No pictures to choose from
blockToPicture 0 (Nothing:_) = Nothing                  -- Desired picture failed to load
blockToPicutre 0 (x:_)       = x                        -- Found desired picture!
blockToPicture n (_:xs)      = blockToPicture (n-1) xs  -- This isn't it; try the next one
```

Adapting Jorge Adriano's suggestion to use `lookup` (which is a good one)

```
import Control.Monad

blockToPicture :: Int -> [Maybe Picture] -> Maybe Picture
blockToPicture n pics = join (lookup n (zip [0..] pics))
```

Since `lookup :: a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b` and `b` here is `Maybe Picture`, we have
a scenario where `lookup` returns `Nothing` if `n` is too big; `Just Nothing` if the desired picture fails to load, and `Just (Just pic)` if the desired picture is found. The `join` function from `Control.Monad` reduces the `Maybe (Maybe Picture)` value that `lookup` returns to the "regular" `Maybe Picture` that we want.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> blocoParaPicture :: Int -> [Picture] -> Picture
> blocoParaPicture b l | b==0 = if elem pic1 l then pic1 else text "X"
>                      | b==1 = if elem pic2 l then pic2 else text "X"
>                      | otherwise = if elem pic3 l then pic3 else text "X"
> ```
>
> I'm getting the error "Variable not in scope" to the pictures.

The expression `elem x xs` checks if a given `x` is in a list `xs`. In your code when you write `pic1`, there's no such variable in scope, it isn't defined anywhere. In any case you don't want to search for a specific value in the list, rather you want to know if a given position "exists", that is if the list is long enough.

Also you can't just "write" inside a function with this type. In Haskell input and output is reflected on the types. This is a pure function, that takes some arguments and calculates a result, no side effects.

So what you can do here is return a `Maybe Picture`, which has values `Nothing` or `Just pic` depending whether you can return a picture or not. Or you can use `Either String Picture`, where values are of the form `Left string` or `Right pic`. Lets go for this latter option.

```
blocoParaPicture :: Int -> [Picture] -> Either String Picture
```

In terms of implementation we could diverge from the subject to get into a discussion of error management (since the problem is that access to a position may fail). But at this point I think it's best to avoid that detour so lets keep it (relatively) simple.

**direct recursion (simplest)**

The simplest most direct method would be direct recursion (as suggested by @chepner in the comments below).

```
blocoParaPicture :: Int -> [Picture] -> Either String Picture
blocoParaPicture _ []     = Left "X"
blocoParaPicture 0 (x:_)  = Right x
blocoParaPicture n (x:xs) = safe (n-1) xs
```

**making sure `!!` succeds**

If you do want to use the standard access function `!!`, one way to go about it (but potentially inefficient in the general case) would be to construct a "safe" infinite list.

```
import Data.List 

blocoParaPicture :: Int -> [Picture] -> Either String Picture
blocoParaPicture n xs = zs !! n 
                        where zs = [Right x | x <- xs] ++ repeat (Left "X")
```

The list `zs` is an infinite list made up of two lists. First  `[Right x | x <- xs]` which just like your original list, but each element `x` becomes `Right x`. Then from then onwards all elements are of the form `Left "X"` to indicate failure. In general the above approach can be inefficient. If you look for a big `n` in a list:

```
[Right 1, Right 2] ++ [Left "X", Left "X", ...
```

you are doing many unnecessary steps, since you could stop when the first list ends. But works just fine for small `n`.

**using `lookup`**

Yet another possibility, similar to your attempt to use the `elem` function, would be to use `lookup` on indices. This function is safe by design.

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

Following this approach you first construct the list,

```
[(0,x0), (1,x1), (2,x2) ...(k,xk)]
```

and then look for your given `n` to return the associated `xn` (or `Nothing`).

```
blocoParaPicture' :: Int -> [Picture] -> Maybe Picture
blocoParaPicture' n xs = lookup n (zip [1..] xs)
```

This returns `Nothing` when not found though. But if you wish to, you can convert to  `Either` via `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`.

```
blocoParaPicture :: Int -> [Picture] -> Either String Picture
blocoParaPicture n xs = maybe (Left "X") Right (lookup n (zip [1..] xs))
```

This is certainly a bit too complex when all you want is a simple access function. But can be handy in situations where things are not as simple.

Comment: In the pathological case where `n` is *way* bigger then `length xs`, it would be more efficient to just check `n > length xs` than iterating over a large enough swath of the infinite list.

Comment: Or just write the recursion directly instead of using `!!`: `bPP _ [] = Left "X"; bPP 0 (x:_) = Right x; bPP n (x:xs) = bPP (n-1) xs`.

Comment: Indeed you're right, I considered that. In any case he's a beginner and  supposedly looking at a list with just 3 elements... every approach teaches him something.

Comment: Added your suggestion, perhaps that's best. Trying to stick with `!!` might have made it unnecessarily complicated.  I also looked up a "safe" alternative to `!!` before but only found `Data.List.Safe`, but it uses the same name as the standard functions, and that would be confusing here.